# Split array of arguments into individual arguments and pass them into PHPUnit ->with()

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to use `@dataProvider` to refactor my horrendous-looking unit tests, however I am unsure how I can pass arguments to my PHPunit mockbuilder `->with()` block without it thinking that I'm trying to pass an array...

```
$myArgs = array('arg1', 'arg2', 3);

$myStub->expects($this-once())
    ->method('myFunction')
    ->with($myArgs)
```

I would like `->with($myArgs)` to be interpreted as `->with('arg1', 'arg2', 3)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument unpacking:

```php
$myStub->expects($this-once())
    ->method('myFunction')
    ->with(...$myArgs);
```